# How to target all files in root folder and subfolders except some in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy, grunt-contrib-compress

I'm trying to archive all files (including subfolders and files in them) in the root folder with some exceptions.

Here's the list of the files:

```
 var fileList = [
    '**/*',
    '!archive.zip',
    '!.sass-cache/*',
    '!assets/*',
    '!node_modules/*',
    '!.bowerrc',
    '!.editorconfig',
    '!.gitattributes',
    '!.gitignore',
    '!.jshintrc',
    '!bower.json',
    '!Gruntfile.js',
    '!package.json',
    '!README.md',
    '!sublime.sublime-project',
    '!sublime.sublime-workspace',
  ];
```

And here's the `grunt-contrib-compress` config:

```
    compress: {
      main: {
        options: {
          archive: 'archive.zip'
        },
        files: [
          { src: [fileList], dest: 'archive/' }, // includes files in path
        ]
      }
    }
```

But I can't make it work. Seems that the process is stuck in endless loop and it keeps archiving itself over and over. I tried adding the name of the archive to the exception list, however it didn't help.

How can I get all the files archived from the root folder and subfolders with certain exceptions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't write out my exclusions as part of my array of files to be processed, instead I typically use the `filter` attribute for exclusions.  An easier approach would be to simply copy the files you do want into a specified folder, and then archiving the contents of that folder.

Comment: Also, your infinite loop might be ocurring because you didn't exclude the `archive` folder from your selection.

Comment: Copying files to a folder will result in redundant copies of the files. I did include `!archive.zip` in the list of exclusion, I also added `!archive/*`, but it didn't help either.

Comment: If you're worried about redundant copies, set the folder to untracked, and once you've compressed the files, use `grunt-contrib-clean` to clean out the redundant files from the staging folder.  If that's just not an acceptable solution, I'll write out the programatic way for you to filter as an answer, but that approach will hit scaling issues.